# Write img to partition in SSD. dual boot Windows and Chromefy Chrome OS

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, multi-boot, google-chrome-os

I'm using a [Matebook x pro](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/laptops/matebook-x-pro/) running Windows and with [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) as my boot manager. Yesterday I found out about [Chromefy](https://github.com/imperador/chromefy) and really wanted to try and make my own Chrome OS build for my Matebook.

I managed to make the Chromium/Chrome OS hybrid bootable and it worked perfectly booting from a USB. When I discarded that and tried to dual boot Chromium and Windows the problems started.

After following [these instructions](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uBU4IObDI8IFhSjeCMvKw46O4vKCnfeZTGF7Jx8Brno/edit?usp=sharing) and restarting to boot up Chromium it did not show up in rEFInd or anywhere else. I believe I could have possibly done something wrong when getting rid of the extra partitions but im not sure. [File I'm supposed to make changes to](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1F8GdcJHkduOyhef_hA4tSbRwOJBKGD2v). If anyone could tell me exactly what i should get rid of it would be helpful.

Now after trying that and failing I tried booting up Chrome OS in the USB and installing it to an external HDD with roughly these Command (I changed the drive):

```
chronos
sudo su
cd /
sudo   /usr/sbin/chromeos-install  --dst  /dev/sda  --skip_postinstall
```

It 'Successfully Installed' but when trying to boot up the HDD from rEFInd it did not show up at all, so I gave up on that and tried another approach.

I deleted all the partitions I had created for Chrome OS and formatted that 50GB space as a normal exfat partition. I figured if I could write a bootable IMG to a USB I could also do the same with this partition but nope. I tried a plethora of different programs to try and achieve this and none worked. I assume its because it formats the whole disk and I can't really format my SSD, but surely there must be a way to boot up this image from a partition the same way we do with USBs.

I tried:

1. Etcher
2. [Lili](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download)
3. Rufus
4. [easyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) (this works differently though I still think it could help me. I would appreciate tips on this one.)
5. [win32 disk imager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/)
6. Chromebook recovery utility

I know dd could be also an option, but I don't know dd enough to do this myself. If anyone could help me with any of this or tell me which way I should be approaching this I'd greatly appreciate it.

I *don't* have Linux installed.I just used a live USB for all of the steps that required Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install without --skip_postinstall

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you [edit] your question to explain *why* you are suggesting this? Thanks

Comment: ill try this but i dont see how it can help